# Truncate reverse in Django

Tags: django

I just want to truncate reverse chars in Djanog. For example I have this value `Image/path_image.jpg` then, the output that I want is path_image.jpg. The first 6 chars should not be included in displaying the characters. Currently I've been using `{{ img_photos.photos |truncatechars:9}}` but It includes `Image`. Is there any documentation or idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) for this:

```
{{ img_photos.photos|slice:"6:" }}
```

For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> Template('{{ foo|slice:"6:" }}').render(Context({'foo': 'Image/path_image.jpg'}))
'path_image.jpg'
```

Comment: `{{ ...|slice:"6:" }}` instead of `{{ ...|truncatechars:"6:" }}` ?